# PHP preg_match with < and >

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I use `preg_match()` to match a string like : `a[b]`.

I want to get the value `a` and `b`.

So I tried to use :

```
preg_match("/(?P<first>\w+)[(?P<second>\w+)]/", $typed_term, $matches);
```

But it fails.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets:

```
/(?P<first>\w+)\[(?P<second>\w+)\]/
```

Comment: Oh ! @Blender, thanks for your fast reply ! It save my time ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
preg_match("/(?P<first>\w+)\[(?P<second>\w+)\]/", $typed_term, $matches)
```

let me know if that works..